# How to use and maintain assault rifles brought to the past

Tags: science-based, technology, weapons, time-travel, medieval

A group of time-traveling soldiers ends up in 15th century Europe.  They have an arsenal of either AR's or SMG's and need to use them until their resources (ammo) run out.  How can they maintain the guns and make new supplies while still using them?

Comment: What do you mean with preserve them? And, more important, how does your time travel work, since you are worried about preserving some weapons but not the soldiers bearing them?

Comment: 1851 is around the time we started having cartridge ammunition (the fore-runner to modern systems, and I do mean "fore-runner") - so just up the passage of time by a few hundred years or put another way - you cannot (with SMG or AR-15s)

Comment: Hasn't this question (how to manufacture modern stuff in the medieval period) been asked before?  The answer is always the same, "you can't."  The manufacturing base required for modern chemistry and metalurgy doesn't exist.

Comment: They take back a magic box which 3D prints infinite ammo without needing any batteries or raw materials. Should I post this as an answer?

Comment: Oh right, I see the question is tagged `science-based`. How about: "They take back a high tech box which 3D prints ... etc"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could medieval people produce automatic firearms if they had access to the schematics?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/10610/could-medieval-people-produce-automatic-firearms-if-they-had-access-to-the-schem)

Comment: @JGreenwell, check out what I found as a duplicate.  If you disagree, I'll revert the vote and simply post it as a "relevant question."

Comment: Related: [How fast could a civilization advance if given access to information to the future](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/5140/how-fast-could-a-civilization-advance-if-given-access-to-information-from-future?rq=1)

Comment: @JBH works for me, better than the related question I found

Comment: I have to say, I don't see either of these links as a duplicate of this question.  It's not about manufacturing weapons, just supplies.  And it's not about advancing the civilization they time travel to (while it might be a side effect, it's not part of the question).  I'm voting to leave open.

Comment: I just did a large edit.  If you aren't happy with it in any way, please re-edit it or do a roll-back.  I added/changed tags and also did a strong edit of the title and body.

Comment: @Eric clifford Goose-grease and gun oil are radically diferent, your chemist would need to close that gap.

Comment: This is a problem of logistics. Your time-travelling soldiers should have made sure they had ongoing supplies of ammunition. Also, the maintenance of weapons is standard practice for soldiers, even on the battlefield.

Comment: Until their ammo runs out? A few drops of oil in the receiver of a previously well maintained weapon.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To clean a weapon in the field, they need gun oil, rags/patches, and a few simple tools/gadgets. A properly equipped soldier will carry those and clean the weapon after each day's hike through swamp and dust. A soldier would also carry a couple hundred rounds of ammunition per weapon -- five to ten 30-round magazines for a SMG or assault rifle, half a dozen 100 to 200 round belts for a SAW.

- If they store their weapons in a well-made box, they won't have to clean the weapons every day, so their bottle of gun oil will last longer. I would say the supplies they carry with then should be enough to clean the weapon more than a dozen times.
- Parts like springs and firing pins don't break all that often if the weapon is simply stored, and fired and then cleaned afterwards from time to time.

So cleaning supplies won't run out before the ammo does if they take the AR out of storage, fire roughly a magazine worth of ammo, and then clean the weapon.

It would be different if they somehow manage to manufacture new ammunition. This new ammo will be **much** more corrosive on the barrels, and there will be more of it as well.

Some hobby shooters and hunters do reload their cartridge cases. They collect the empties, replace the percussion primer, fill in powder, and put a new bullet on top. Usually this involves industrial-quality primer, propellant, and bullets ...

- The bullets would probably be unjacketed lead. Hard on the barrels and less accurate in flight.
- A home-made primer would be less reliable, and also corrosive.
- Black powder would be less powerful, further reducing accuracy, and also dirtier.
- The weapons might no longer fire on semiautomatic or automatic.

---

**Pet Peeve:** An alternate history is when a general didn't make the blunder he did in the real world, or when the heir to the throne didn't die as an infant, or when the exploration ship got blown off course and discovered a continent early. Modern-day people with modern-day gear in a historical setting are **time travel**, not **alternate history**.

Comment: Great detail on your answer.  I agree with your pet peeve and I changed the tags to match.  If the OP doesn't like my change, s/he or course can change it back.

Comment: " A soldier would also carry a couple hundred rounds of ammunition per weapon " ... I believe this is the case in the USA, but for Europe (example in France), you're not provided with enough ammo to fight for the entire battle. [I guess you are supposed to take the ammo of dead poeple around you?].

Comment: Good to see a commonsense answer. Soldiers maintaining their weapons to keep them in good working order is standard military practice. They have it drilled into them from day one of their training.

Comment: @holeohlw, it is a question of weight. I believe seven 30-round magazines for a M16-style weapon are lighter than five 20-round magazines for a G3-style or FAL-style weapon. One of the reasons why almost everybody switched to 5.56mm. Then there is the problem what else a rifleman must carry -- belts for the squad MG, mortar rounds, LAWs, grenades, ...

Comment: @holeohlw That is frightening and ups my respect for French military members (I know of/have heard of/have shown up as backup when groups have run out of ammo despite having near or over 500 rounds apiece) Also, I have the same pet-peeve re: alternate history as o.m. so glad someone pointed it out :)

Comment: @JGreenwell, googling a bit (that isn't really my area of experience) the French armor vest will take pouches for three magazines. Two of these pouches plus one in the rifle give 210 rounds, which is as much as US Airborne infantry were supposed to carry if they are hauling lots of water and batteries up and down the hills in OIF.

Comment: yeah, standard was between 210-270 (if you included the extra magazine you initially put in your weapon) with US Marines too - I just know of times when double that wasn't enough (think Battle of Fallujah, 1st, 2nd or 3rd, or when we started re-taking roads & areas like Hit or Bronze)

Comment: "Black powder would be less powerful, further reducing accuracy," - It's much worse than that. It doesn't take much lower power to make the operating system fail, as there is not enough tapped-off energy to work the action. Plus, you simply can't get the long, controlled burn you need in black powder, so the reloading process becomes even less reliable. Plus, not only does barrel fouling become greater, so does the fouling of the recoil system itself.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast, that's my last bullet point, I think. But even hand-loading single rounds in a modern rifle will fire a lot faster than a muzzle-loader.

Answer (score 3):

Even ignoring maintenance, a modern rifle like an AK 47 can go a few years in decent conditions (open air, not in the rain or particles) before its performance becomes problematic. And even then, a quick cleanup routine would put it back in decent shape. An AK can go months in bad conditions (basically drowned) before it becomes dangerous to use. Ammo can go years before underperforming. To put it in numbers, a decade can go by without use if your characters put them away properly.

But to extend their use, mostly in terms of getting more ammo, is simply not possible using 16th century technology. Even if they could recoup and recharge the shells, medieval tech isnt up to par to get you proper gunpowder needed. A proper chemist and modern processing is needed for that.

Comment: Since you can empty an AK firearm in about 30 seconds on full auto, ammo is going to be a huge issue.

Comment: No professional uses full auto. 3 burst maybe but not full.

Comment: @cde, only modern weapons have a burst limiter. And many of those still have full auto for good reasons -- there are tactical situations where it is appropriate. But then, you can empty an AK in 3 seconds on full auto, and in less than 30 seconds firing semi-auto single shots.

Comment: @o.m. OP is asking about modern weapons.

Comment: @cde The AK-47, which this snswer specified, does not have a three-round burst capability. Of course it really doesn't qualify as a "modern" weapon either, with a design that is over 70 years old.

Comment: according to the US, anything made after 1899 is a modern gun (and requires a completely different license) - and the AK-47 (both recent and old models) have shown up in modern conflicts. They are still effective and certainly would be an option for this

Comment: This. The US field manual for the M1, .30 Caliber Rifle says to **avoid excessive cleaning of your weapon**. Repeated disassembly can cause undue wear. How to clean an AK to fire the *next* (and last) 500 rounds? Oil the receiver.

Answer (score 1):

Ammo will be the biggest issue, not cleaning supplies or replacement parts.  You can use basically any oil in modern firearms, they aren't picky.  Snobs will tell you you absolutely have to use XYZ premium oil specially made for firearms, but that's nonsense.  Nearly any lubricant will work; vegetable oil, olive oil, even oil from rendered fat.

And modern guns don't even need to be cleaned that often.  Look up some mud tests on youtube, even guns notorious for needing maintenance like the M16 are surprisingly tolerant of dirt.

As for replacement parts, once again, they aren't as immediately necessary as ammo.  I would expect to get through at least 1,000 rounds before I have to replace anything at all.  Probably even 10,000.  And some parts should never need replaced; I'd expect an AR15 lower receiver to still be fine for my grandchildren to use for instance.